# File fully populating

Tags: java, file, unix, bufferedwriter

I have this piece of code that is supposed to insert data in a table and fill a txt file with the same data.  However I am finding that the table is being filled with the appropriate 2019 rows but the file only contains 1639 with a `[Incomplete last line]` message at the bottom.  What is causing this?

```
while(ora_rs.next()){
    sql_stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO SCHED_BUNDLES_TEMP_TEST VALUES (" +
         ora_rs.getString("BUNDLE")+", " +
         ora_rs.getString("DROPPER_ID")+", '" +
         ora_rs.getString("SCHED_DT")+"')");

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date new_date = (Date)formatter.parse(ora_rs.getString("SCHED_DT"));
    SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    String final_string = newFormat.format(new_date);
    out.write(ora_rs.getString("BUNDLE")+"|"+ora_rs.getString("DROPPER_ID")+"|"+final_string+"\n");

         ii++;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to print the counter to see how many lines were actually written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you have a buffered stream and you are not close()ing or flush()ing the stream which means the end of the file is not being written (as its still in memory)